# How to separate nested rows of one column into new columns SQL (Big Query)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, nested

I'm pretty new to SQL and I'm trying to separate some nested data in our sales database. We pipe our data from Shopify and there are certain variable product titles that I'm trying to separate from the order, to create new columns with those strings. The query I'm using is:

```
(select name as order_number,
      (select custom.value.value as custom_text1,
      from `ORDERS_TABLE`,
      UNNEST (line_items) line, 
      UNNEST (line.value.properties) custom
      where custom.value.name = "custom name 1" ) custom_text1,
      (select custom.value.value as custom_text2,
      from `ORDERS_TABLE`,
      UNNEST (line_items) line, 
      UNNEST (line.value.properties) custom
      where custom.value.name = "custom name 2" ) custom_text2,
from `ORDERS_TABLE`, 
  UNNEST (line_items) line, 
  UNNEST (line.value.properties) custom)
```

The return is showing null for the new columns. The end goal is to create individual columns for each value.name row and fill in those column rows with the corresponding data in value.value.

In the Select* of the table, it returns the following per order:

[Image of data we want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhrNf.png)

The following is how we would like to see the data returned:

[Image of data we want to receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTjSs.png)

Feel free to direct me to any other posts with similar queries if any are available.

Thank you!!